# Does requesting a stack trace from a particular thread require all threads to be at a safe point?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, jvmti

When requesting the stack trace from another thread via `Thread#getStackTrace()` or `ThreadMXBean#getThreadInfo(long[], int)`, do all threads have to enter a safe point and thus have to wait until all other threads have entered a safe point?

[This blog](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2016/02/why-most-sampling-java-profilers-are.html) seems to suggest that this is the case:

> You hit a global safepoint whether you are sampling a single thread or all threads (at least on OpenJDK, Zing is slightly different but as a profiler vendor OpenJDK is your assumption.)

That would mean that it would be just as intrusive (in terms of high overhead due to an increased frequency of global safe point hits) to get the stack track from a single thread than it is to get all stack traces.

But is that actually/still true for OpenJDK? Do you have any pointers to why that is or to the relevant source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OpenJDK (up to current JDK 13) `Thread.getStackTrace()` still runs at the global stop-the-world safepoint:

[Thread.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/354025d0427d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1589)

```
public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
    if (this != Thread.currentThread()) {
        ....
        StackTraceElement[][] stackTraceArray = dumpThreads(new Thread[] {this});
```

This goes down to [ThreadService::dump_stack_traces](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/354025d0427d/src/hotspot/share/services/threadService.cpp#l300), which executes [`VM_ThreadDump`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/354025d0427d/src/hotspot/share/services/threadService.cpp#l309) operation in a VM thread. All `VM_*` operations used to run at the global safepoint.

[JEP 312: Thread-Local Handshakes](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/312) introduced in JDK 10, provides a per-thread safepoint mechanism. Now [`VM_Handshake`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/354025d0427d/src/hotspot/share/runtime/handshake.cpp#l65) and all its descendants do not require a global safepoint:

```
class VM_Handshake: public VM_Operation {
  const jlong _handshake_timeout;
 public:
  bool evaluate_at_safepoint() const { return false; }
```

However, `VM_ThreadDump` is not such an operation. Neither is [`VM_GetStackTrace`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/354025d0427d/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiEnv.cpp#l1530) used to implement JVM TI GetStackTrace function.

There is an open issue [JDK-8201641](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8201641) to make use of thread-local handshakes to get a stack trace of a single thread some time in future.

Comment: So that means a sampling profiler based on that will inflict stop-the-world pauses on the application at every sampling interval, right?

Comment: @Felix Exactly. This is one of the reasons that motivated me to develop [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) which does not rely on safepoint-based APIs.

Comment: Does the wall clock option of async profiler also avoid safepoint-based APIs?